# VSCode C++ Intellisense doesn't work even include paths are correct

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked my `includePath` variable in `c_cpp_properties.json` multiple times and I believe they point to the right directories. However, VSCode still green-squiggle include statements saying that it can't find include files.

Any ideas on what might be incorrect?

Comment: I started to set absolute paths (instead of relative to ${workspaceFolder}) one by one and it seems to be helping...